# Populate dropdown using curly braces + angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the curly braces syntax interpolation is used to bind the data from model to view in angularjs.

Generally we display text using it.

Can we populate dropdownlist using the `{{}}` syntax in any way?

Comment: Why not use `ng-options`?

Comment: But along with ng-options we have to use ng-model. And I am searching for a technique, which can allow us to populate data without ng-model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="item.value">{{item.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great! Thanx a lot. Now I need a bit of guidance of yours. Now say I am having multiple dropdownlists and I want to send the selection of those dropdownlists in an array to the server. How do we do it. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/tushar$20sharma/angular/2R7_pCC7E1o/vRsYTfNhXYgJ

Comment: What is that link for?

Comment: To send the selection, you would need to use `ng-model`.

Comment: The link contains the code that I have done. Please refer the latest version of the issue on the following link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780840/post-a-list-of-selections-in-an-array-to-server-using-ng-model                  I am getting an empty array in the POST tab of the firebug

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can *populate* a dropdownlist using the curly braces in angular, but it won't have the expected effect.
If you want to have the data-binding in your select box, you should use the [select directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) which writes the `option` tags  in a similar way the [`ng-repeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) directive would.
Here's an example:

**js**:

```
$scope.selectables = [
    { label: 'A', value: 1},
    { label:'B', value: 2},
    { label: 'C', value: 3}
];

// this is the model that's used for the data binding in the select directive
// the default selected item
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.selectables[0];
```

**html**:

```
<select 
   ng-model="selectedItem" 
   ng-options="o.label for o in selectables">
</select>
<p>Selected item value: {{selectedItem.value}}</p>
```

Here's a demo to clear things up: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/TU6tp/

Comment: Is it not possible without ng-model? Coz in my situation with this technique I will have to put two ng-models in the select directive which would create a conflict

Comment: Have a look at the updated issue:               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780840/post-a-list-of-selections-in-an-array-to-server-using-ng-model?noredirect=1#comment27692672_18780840

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can populate a dropdownlist this way :

```
<select ng-model="myItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
```

The selected item will be stored in `$scope.myItem`.

Check this page : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway to populate it without ng-model? Because in my app I am having problem. the two-way binding of ng-model is creating problems.

Comment: the code can be found on the following plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/oy073r?p=preview

Comment: Note that ng-options creates its own scope when binding the selection to the model. The trick I use to get around this is to create a "ui" object in the controller's scope `$scope.ui = {};` and bind to it `ng-model="ui.myItem"`.

Comment: Nice idea Jim. But the problem I am having : I am actually using ng-model to populate the data in the dropdownlist. In UI there is an "Add More" button that will add new dropdownlists dynamically on click. Now I want to send the selections of the user to the server in an array. We cannot use ng-model because it is already bound to the dropdownlist data. Hence the two-way binding would restrict us to do that. How do we send the array of selections to the server uisng angularjs directives?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/tushar$20sharma/angular/2R7_pCC7E1o/vRsYTfNhXYgJ

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="searchDropdown" ng-class="{active: isDropdownActive}">
            <option ng-repeat="item in data.results" value="{{ item[settings.filterOptions[0].value] }}" >{{ item[settings.filterOptions[0].value] }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can we have something without the use of ng-model? Or rather can we have such a structure that can help us in a case where we are receiving a different type of data and we are sending a different type of data. Becoz ng-model binds the tag two - way limiting us to send same data two way